# React Material Select: The expected type comes from property 'renderValue' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SelectProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

React Material Select is giving the following error. How can I fix this? The error is on Render Value. I am using typescript, not sure how to fix. What should I place on renderValue line?

**Error:**

```
Type '(selected: Array<number>) => string' is not assignable to type '(value: unknown) => ReactNode'.
  Types of parameters 'selected' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.ts(2322)
Select.d.ts(111, 3): The expected type comes from property 'renderValue' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SelectProps'
```

**Code:**

```
const [testValue, setTestValue] = useState<Array<number>>([]);

<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel id="test-select-label">Location</InputLabel>
  <Select
    multiple
    fullWidth
    labelId="test-select-label"
    id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
    variant="outlined"
    label="Location"
    value={testValue}
    name="first"
    onChange={(event: any) => {
      setTestValue(event.target.value);
    }}
    input={<OutlinedInput label="Tag" />}
    renderValue={(selected: Array<number>) =>
      serviceLocationOptions
        .filter(x => selected.includes(x.serviceLocationId))
        .map(x => x.name)
        .join(', ')
    }
  >
    {serviceLocationOptions.map(item => (
      <MenuItem
        key={item.serviceLocationId}
        value={item.serviceLocationId}
      >
        <Checkbox
          checked={testValue.includes(item.serviceLocationId)}
        />
        <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. The code [works fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-mui-5-xme4f2?file=/src/App.tsx) (some time is required for ts to load).

Comment: hi @user4980215 its something with typescript errors, or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Typescript you cannot assign a function with *more specific* parameter to  a function with *less specific* parameter. For example:

```
const f: (v: unknown) => string = (a: number) => "hi";

Error: Type '(a: number) => string' is not assignable to type '(v:
unknown) => string'.
```

There are two solutions:

1. Update Meterial UI to the last version. They have changed the types and your code just works:

```
value?: T | '';
renderValue?: (value: T) => React.ReactNode;
```

2. Move the `selected` type down to the point of usage:

```
renderValue={(selected: unknown) =>
  serviceLocationOptions
    .filter((x) =>
      (selected as Array<number>).includes(x.serviceLocationId)
    )
    .map((x) => x.name)
    .join(", ")
}
```

<s>Or just use any.</s>

Comment: why did you delete "Any" data type as option? that will work also,

Comment: Yes, but `any` is a last resort.

Comment: interesting, why is it last resort over unknown?

Comment: `unknown` is safer. I meant in general though.